# Search API ItemType missing Node

Tags: views, search

I am using Search API and search views to add facet blocks into my views page. It works perfect on my test site with only search/facet/views related modules.

But on my working site, when I add Search Index, the ItemType is missing "Node" selection, instead, it is showing "Content". I have updated all modules, but can't figure out why "Node" option is missing.

Anyone has ideas on this?

[image]

Comment: What version of search api are you running ?

Comment: All Newest version: search_api-7.x-1.14, facetapi-7.x-1.5, ctools-7.x-1.7, views-7.x-3.10, entity-7.x-1.6. We have near 100 modules for this site, is there any modules that limit the "Node" option?.

Comment: Why would you want to have a Node option ? What is the different between Node and Content ?

Comment: The difference is "Node" works, but "Content" doesn't work.

Comment: Matt, You need to provide more details about what you mean by "does not work". I have used all those modules for over a year (like everyday) and "it works fine to be."

Comment: For search_api, search_api_views, and related modules, do they require php 5.4 or higher? my current working site is 5.3.3, maybe this is the reason. I will have to try lower php version at my test server.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the "**Node**" Item type. Using the "**Content**" is going to index all your nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. The facet won't show up in the view page.

Comment: When using the Content option with commerce, product reference fields will not be pulled.

Comment: Same issue here.  Two environments, one has node one has content.  I'm getting different results on the two somehow.